# Control a toggle button through another button

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

I have a toggle button which is working, i just want to create a button that will only interect with the toggle, when i click the button the toggle will go on, when i click again in the button the toggle will go off.

Toggle.html

```
<ion-toggle class="toggle-small" toggle-class="toggle-calm" id="toggle" (ionChange)="add(ioToggle.checked)"  #ioToggle ></ion-toggle>
```

Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add `[(ngModel)]="status"`

```
<ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="status" class="toggle-small" toggle-class="toggle-calm" id="toggle" (ionChange)="add(ioToggle.checked)"  #ioToggle ></ion-toggle>
```

Then add a button:

```
<!-- Bind the click event to a method -->
<button ion-button (click)="buttonClick($event)">
  Click me!
</button>
```

in `.ts`:
First define `status` at the beginning of the class, and then define the `buttonClick` function:

```
...
status = false;
...
buttonClick(event) {
    this.status = !this.status 
}
```

Comment: Working like a charm, may god bless you.

Comment: Could you exmplain it to me how, the ngModel is working please ?

Comment: This is called `Two-way` binding. It means changing `status` from `ts` file will change its value in `html` and vice versa. Therefore, when we invert the value of `status` in `buttonClick()`, you will see its effect in html. 

https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/components/app_structure/two_way_data_binding.html

Answer (score 0):

```js
function switchx(){
var x = document.getElementById('input1')

x.checked = !x.checked}

/*the stopit function prevents being able to click on the switch */

function stopit(){
var x = document.getElementById('input1')

x.checked = !x.checked


}
```

```css
#button2{
display:none;
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}
```

```html
<h2>Toggle Switch</h2>

<label class="switch">
  <input id='input1' type="checkbox" onclick='stopit()'>
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label>

<button id='button1' onclick='switchx()'>switch</button>
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your response, please allow me to be more specific about what i want to do.
I want to create a button that will simulate my click on the toggle ( i will hide the toggle ), imagine when i click on the button for the first time the toggle wil be on, if i click again it will go off ...

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. what do you mean by 'simulate my click on the toggle? do you want the toggle button to disappear?

Comment: Nor sir, please take a look at this image https://i.imgur.com/eEdIOhK.png 

I want when i click on the hand button the toggle will go on, and when i click again the the hand button the toggle will go off.

Comment: ahh, you want to create a button that will toggle a switch

Comment: Yes i think that's it, Cause my toggle is doing what i want him to do, but instead of switching him bymyself i want to create a button that will do the job ( when i click on it )

Comment: Hello sir i got, TypeError: Cannot create property 'checked' on boolean 'false'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171115/discussion-between-eyta-and-dcr).